# delete model and update view in backbonejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following Backbone View:

```
    Chatbox.Views.Message = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($("#tmplt-Message").html()),

    events: {
        "click a.remove_link" : "clear"
    },
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'remove');
        this.model.on('clear', this.clear);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
    },

    render: function () {
        return $(this.el).append(this.template(this.model.toJSON())) ;
    },

    clear: function() {
        this.model.destroy();
    }
});
```

When I click on the link with the class `remove_link` the `clear()` function is called properly and `destroy()` is executed.

How can I call the `clear()` externally, in my case I have a collection and I want to delete a model in this collection. Currently I'm trying doing this:

```
    message = Chatbox.ChatLogCollection.where({ hash: hash});
    message.clear();
    Chatbox.ChatLogCollection.remove(message);
```

But I get:
       TypeError: message.clear is not a function

How can I call `clear()` to remove the model from the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first line is searching for a model within the collection, clear() won't work because clear() is associated with the view, not the model, but you're calling it on the model. If it is the model, you can use `collectionInstance.remove(message)` or `message.destroy()` directly. However, you'd then need the view to listen for the model being removed to have the view re-rendered.

To check, add `console.log(message)` to see what you're getting.

Comment: When I try to `message.remove()` I get `message.remove is not a function`. And how could I bind the view to listen to the change?

Comment: `this.model.on('remove', this.render, this);` Is Chatbox.ChatLogCollection the collection object, or an instance of the collection object?

Comment: It's an instance of the Collection Object

Comment: The where() function returns an array. Try findWhere() which will only return one model.